# Realm Android and large data sets with multipolygon calculations

Tags: android, realm, coordinates, polygon, large-data

I'm parsing a Json file which contains a lot of multipolygons to Realm. I've set it up the following way:

**RealmMultiPolygon class:**

```
public int dangerLevel;
public int timeOfDay;

public RealmList<RealmPolygon> realmPolygons
```

**RealmPolygon class:**

```
public RealmList<RealmPolygonCoordinate> coordinates;
```

**RealmPolygonCoordinate**

```
public double latitude;
public double longitude;
```

As far as items concern:

- RealmMultiPolygon contains 8 items
- RealmPolygon  contains 22260 items
- RealmPolygonCoordinate contains 352241 items

I'm trying to figure out if a RealmPolygon is in a direction where i'm looking at and near my current location. I'm taking 31 locationsamples with bearings like this:

```
private void calculateUserDirectionLocations() {
    Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "update the locationbar");
    if(compassData < 0) {
        return;
    }
    int step = 50;

    int bearingstep = 1;

    double bearing = Math.round(compassData / bearingstep) * bearingstep;

    if(userLocation != null) {
        if(Math.abs(bearing - oldBearing) > 1) {
            locationSamples.clear();

            Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "START location samples");

            for(int i = 0; i <= Constants.MAX_DISTANCE; i+=step) {
                if (i % step == 0) {
                    locationSamples.add(locationWithBearing((double) i));
                }
            }

            Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "END location samples");

            updateColors();
            oldBearing = bearing;
        }
    }
}
```

Where compassData is gained from the RotationVectorSensor (value between 0 and 360 degrees) and the MAX_Distance is 1.5Km.

Now if I want to know if one of the 31 locationSample points is near a polygon I have to loop through all the polygonCoordinates which I currently have in my Realm database 31 times. which means:
31 * 352241 = 10919471

This is incredibly slow but I can't really seem to find a better solution for this. Anyone have an idea how to do this better / faster?

**Update 1**
At the moment i'm looping through the coordinates like this:

```
for(RealmMultiPolygon rmp : area.avalanche.multiPolygon) {
                if(rmp.timeOfDay == 2) {
                    for (RealmPolygon polygon : rmp.realmPolygons) {
                        for(LatLng sample : locationSamples) {
                            tempPoint = new LatLng(polygon.coordinates.first().latitude, polygon.coordinates.first().longitude);
                            if(SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(tempPoint, sample) <= 500) {
                                coords.add(tempPoint);
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You could make it parallel

Comment: *I have to loop through all the polygonCoordinates which I currently have in my Realm database 31 times* how do you do this?

Comment: can you show the code block that does the query in realm and the loop?

Comment: what is `area.avalanche.multiPolygon`?

Comment: @TimCastelijns that is the RealmList which contains the MultiPolygons.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed this by coming up with a totally different solution. I'm now creating an image based on the width and height of the area the polygons are in as a background task. Then I calculate the pixel position based on the locationsample I take and use the getPixel method to get the pixels on that position. This is way faster than looping through each polygon.